# Перенос "и", "в", "на"

Tags: перенос

Добрый день уважаемые знатоки русского языка.
Мне сказали, что нельзя в конце строки оставлять "и", "в", "на" и подобные, что нужно обязательно переносить на новую строку. Что это вообще за правила такие, где о них можно узнать? Весь интернет перерыл, не могу найти ничего об этом, видел что люди тоже ищут, но информация урывками, нет полной картины.
Объясните, пожалуйста, какие и как переносить, или дайте ссылку на материал, процитируйте, что угодно, очень нужно разобраться в вопросе :)

Comment: http://studopedia.ru/4_51586_pravila-nabora-i-verstki.html  http://samzan.ru/68260
В книжных изданиях не следует оставлять в конце строки предлоги и союзы, начинающие предложение, а также однобуквенные союзы и предлоги в середине предложений. В журнальных, газетных, информационных изданиях и изданиях оперативной полиграфии допускается оставлять в конце строки однобуквенные предлоги и союзы внутри предложений, а также трёхбуквенные предлоги, начинающие предложение.

Answer (score 4):

В правилах орфографии и пунктуации такого правила нет.
Искать надо в рекомендациях по верстке, я этого делать не буду, не мой профиль, да и к русскому языку  отношение имеет весьма косвенное.

Но если на словах, то это типографская установка - и она вполне разумна.

Предлоги и союзы (вообще все служебные слова) лучше набирать на той строке, где расположено и само слово, к которому эти служебные слова относятся. 
Т.е. в частности не делать разрыв строки после передлогов и союзов и ***перед***, например, частицей "бы".